# windows.open() method error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

`window.open()` of javascript, it is working fine in other browsers, but in case of `ie-8` it shows some error such as popup.

Comment: Do you mean `window.open()`? Please provide some code relevant to your problem.

Comment: please provide some codes and some screenshots if possible.

Comment: The text "some error" will not cut the mustard. You need to be explicit and tell us _everything._

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting stopped by the pop-up blocker.

Comment: Yeah, and there's nothing you can do to control that via code other than hinting the user to disable popups.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open ("http://www.location.com", "mywindow","status=1,toolbar=1");
```

The allowed parameters are as below

```
status  The status bar at the bottom of the window.
toolbar The standard browser toolbar, with buttons such as Back and Forward.
location    The Location entry field where you enter the URL.
menubar The menu bar of the window
directories The standard browser directory buttons, such as What’s New and What’s Cool
resizable   Allow/Disallow the user to resize the window.
scrollbars  Enable the scrollbars if the document is bigger than the window
height  Specifies the height of the window in pixels. (example: height=’350′)
width   Specifies the width of the window in pixels.
```

(Shamelessly copied from [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml))